# Logo at the end of FlowPane tool bar upon startup

Tags: javafx

I have logo that shows well at the end of my FlowPane derived tool bar after resize as I do:

```
widthProperty().addListener((observable, oldWidth, newWidth) -> {
      positionLogo();
    }
);
```

However, I don't see logo initialy because the width property is not good. I tried the following but it doesn't work:

```
m_primaryStage.setOnShown(e -> {
    m_primaryStage.getScene().getRoot().layout();
    m_toolbarSet.positionLogo();
});
```

And the toolbar set method it:

```
public void positionLogo() {
    double spacerMargin = widthProperty().doubleValue() - getChildrenUnmodifiable().stream().mapToDouble( node -> node.getLayoutBounds().getWidth() ).sum();
    clearConstraints( m_logo );
    setMargin(m_logo, new Insets( 2, 0, 0, spacerMargin));
}
```

Comment: Layouting the children should be done in `layoutChildren`...

Answer (score 0):

The idea works well, I was just setting onShown event handler too late - after the stage was shown already